# Loop through all elements in the div and set all elements tabindex to -1

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I loop through all elements in the div and set all elements `tabindex` to `-1`?

```
$('.somediv').each(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('.somediv *').attr("tabindex","-1");
```

Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.somediv *` selector like following.

```
$('.somediv *').attr("tabindex", "-1");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `.attr()` at this context,

```
$('.somediv').attr("tabindex","-1");
```

And there is no need to iterate over all the elements.

If you want to set `tabindex` to all the children/descendants of `.somediv` then just change your selector.

```
$('.somediv > *').attr("tabindex","-1"); //children
$('.somediv *').attr("tabindex","-1");  //descendants
```

and also if you want to set tabindex to `.somediv` then call `.addBack()` before calling the `.attr()`